# Wireless printing does not work in Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, printing

My Epson ET-2720 loads automatically and prints wirelessly with Ubuntu Mate 18.04. and Linux Mint without installing ANY drivers.
The same Epson printer is found in 20.04 but produces a CUPS error - "server not found - internal error". The same issue occurs on different laptops/PC's.
I have posted this issue on the Ubuntu site. The one or two answers folks were kind enough to offer did not work. I have spent hours trying any and all OF the many suggestions found on The Net, including signing in to the CUPS site and attempting the install there. I would like to know what the hell was changed from 18.04 to 20.04 to cause this issue.
My suspicions are that the ones who know the answer are too arrogant OR entitled and cant be bothered helping those who cant figure it out. I hope I am wrong! Your help will make this product better. I support Linux and wish to continue doing so, but without Ubuntu's support, why should I waste my time and money.
Sorry for venting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read `man apt` and use the `apt changelog` followed by a package name. Can you boot "Ubuntu Mate 18.04" or "Linux Mint" and figure out why the printer works? Do you have access to the `/var/log/` directories of the systems where the printer worked?

Comment: Rants "too arrogant OR entitled...can't be bothered..." are not to your advantage. AskUbuntu (this site) is all volunteers. We answer (for free) questions about Ubuntu. Canonical, a for-profit company packages and releases Ubuntu. They've not the same. We, the volunteers of AskUbuntu will help you solve your problem, even help you determine what your problem is, with your cooperation. Have you asked a question? You seem to be new to AskUbuntu, have you checked the Help [Help] section?

Comment: "I have posted this issue on the Ubuntu site" - could you provide a link to that question? I would like to see what happened.

Comment: Like @waltinator, I too would be interested in knowung the link that is asked for. Whether you are using a wireless or USB connection would also be good to have.

Comment: Decided to read the title! 20.04 has driverless printing with a wireless connection.

Comment: A number of things reached EOL & were thus removed during 2019, eg. Qt4 was replaced with Qt5 in 2012 with Qt4 being announced EOL in 2015, but wasn't removed from Debian & Ubuntu until 2019 (so cups drivers that used Qt4 that worked in 18.04 won't work in 20.04 until modified to use Qt5).  Likewise python2 reached EOL etc..  All of this is documented months before it occurs giving users & maintainers time to adjust, but many companies disregard it (they've made their sales so don't care).

Comment: Hello and thank you all for your responses. That said, I have lost any and all interest in using software that requires so much of my time to get it to work right....just not worth my time.

Comment: Hello again, I wanted to add what I did to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share what I did to get this issue resolved.The system is an (HP-dv7 and Epson ET-2720), I did a fresh install on a new ssd drive. I used a DVD I made from a (20.04.2) ISO back in April. I connected an Ethernet cable, unchecked the boxes for "third party " and "updates" during install.Upon completion, I let the updates run. Then I installed the latest printer drivers from the Epson site.
I now unplugged the Ethernet cable and connected to my WiFi.
Next I opened "Add Printer". Under "Network Printer" I chose the Epson ET-2720 (192.168.X.XX) . On the next column under connection, I chose LPD/LPR queue 'PASSTHRU'. I noticed the Host was the IP number with an additional (:515) added to the IP
Next I hit Forward. On the next page the name of my printer was listed Under both PRINTER and DESCRIPTION. The location was the IP numbers. Next I hit APPLY and the printer was added with the box asking if I wanted to print a test page. The printer works perfectly. I also posted on the Ubuntu-Mate website where I originally posted this issue. I wish to thank all who responded here and other places on the Net regarding this issue.Vince C.